# PostgresSQL -- Restrict listing access when using dbeaver or pgadmin

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I have a schema in Postgres named -- `public`

When I login via dbeaver or pgadmin, I can go to `database > schema > public > tables` and it shows me the list of all tables present in public schema.

Is there anyway to create a user named bob and give access to public schema but only 5 tables in it?

So, when bob logs in to postgres using his password, he can go to `database > schema > public > tables` and ONLY view 5 tables. If he looks in information_schema or other postgres related tables and he finds there are other tables, it is fine. But in dbeaver or pgadmin, he should be able to view ONLY 5 tables.

If bob does select on any other table, it is fine too.

Comment: You can prevent bob from seeing the content of the tables, but there is no way to restrict the listing.

Comment: That's too bad. I wish there was a mechanism.

Comment: I think you'll need a ACL Extension:
https://pgxn.org/dist/acl/1.0.0/